# How to store dynamic array of strings as node property in neo4j using parameter via graphql?

Tags: arrays, node.js, neo4j, graphql

I am using Neo4j(3.2.3) and graphql. I am trying to add multiple phone numbers (dynamically) as array of strings in a single property of a user via graphql. So, a user can have as many phone numbers as s/he wants to add. 
 For E.g.

```
 User{
       "name": "Neo",
       "Job": "Actor",
       "phoneNumber": [
                       "13274564",
                       "23451674",
                       "56454646"
                      ]
        }
```

But I am unable to get the desired result. Could someone please let me know what i am doing wrong?

Here is my graphql typeschema and mutation query of User:

```
    type User{

     name:String
     Job:String
     phoneNumber: [String]
    }


   type Mutation {

    addUser(
      name:String!
      Job:String
      phoneNumber: [String]       
    ): User 
   }
```

And here is my cypher query for resolver:

```
addUser(_, params) {


  let query = `MERGE(u:User {_id:apoc.create.uuid()})
              ON CREATE SET u.name= {name},
                            u.Job= {Job},
                            u.phoneNumber = ["{{phoneNumber},{phoneNumber}}"]
```

When I run this query via GraphiQL adding desired phone numbers, the numbers are not being updated and rather same text phoneNumber is being updated in the database like this:

[image: error in updating the field]

So, can anyone please help me out here? I have gone through apoc procedures as well but still unable to figure out how to write an appropriate cypher query for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing an array of strings for the `phoneNumber` parameter you can just set the `phoneNumber` property on the user node to the `phoneNumber` parameter:

```
MERGE(u:User {_id:apoc.create.uuid()})
  ON CREATE SET u.name= {name},
                u.Job= {Job},
                u.phoneNumber = {phoneNumber}
```

If you want to handle phone number updates (keeping the previous numbers):

```
MERGE(u:User {_id:apoc.create.uuid()})
ON CREATE SET u.name= {name},
              u.Job= {Job}
WITH *
UNWIND {phoneNumber} AS phone
SET u.phoneNumber = coalesce(u.phoneNumber + phone, [phone])
```

A more typical approach with a graph data model would be to model each phone number as a node and connect the phone number nodes to the user node:

```
MERGE(u:User {_id:apoc.create.uuid()})
ON CREATE SET u.name= {name},
              u.Job= {Job}
WITH *
UNWIND {phoneNumber} AS phone
MERGE (p:PhoneNumber {number: phone}
MERGE (u)-[:HAS_PHONE_NUMBER]->(p)
```

This would change your GraphQL schema slightly, to something like this:

```
type User {
  name: String
  job: String
  phoneNumber: [PhoneNumber]
}

type PhoneNumber {
  number: String
}
```

Also be sure to check out the [neo4j-graphql integrations](https://neo4j.com/developer/graphql/) that can drive the Neo4j data model from the GraphQL schema and auto-generate resolvers.

Comment: You always come as the savior for my codes. Really appreciate your effort and your articles and talks as well. One quick question, what should i do if I had to handle 2 different fields as array of strings e,g phoneNumber and email too (keeping the previous data)? I am accepting the answer. Thanks, again !

Comment: Glad it's helpful :-) Two arrays would be similar - you would just iterate over the email addresses as well.

Comment: thanks again :)... truly awesome..I'd try iterating as you mentioned. And  yeah being a neo4j die-hard fan and user, I am certain to check out the neo4j-graphql integrations in the coming days ..!! Its really a pleasure to get a response from one whom I admire :) Have a gr8 day !